# How to override Bootstrap DatePicker to allow arbitrary hours selection?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker, hour

I'm using the [Bootstrap Date picker control](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping) to allow selection of an arbitrary amount of hours. So for example a user could select anywhere between `1 -> 50 hours.`

In the current setup I set the format option to allow only hour selection using `format: 'HH'`, but this limits the max hour selection to 23 hours.

**Question**
Does anyone know how to override the default hour selection values on a Bootstrap Date picker?

In the below date picker selecting an hour *greater* than 23 resets the picker to 0:

[image]

This is the declaration of the Date picker in the script and options:

```
    //Init the Next Update arbitrary hour picker
    $(function () {
        $('#NextUpdateDisplay').datetimepicker({
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            format: 'HH',
            widgetPositioning: {
                horizontal: 'right',
                vertical: 'bottom'
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: its a standard date-time picker hence its showing standard date and time format and its selection. As you want totally different number selection then just use Date picker with separate dropdown showing required hour value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Bootstrap.timepicker.js`, find this line:

```
`this.hour >= 24 ? this.hour = 23`
```

change it to:

```
`this.hour >= 51 ? this.hour = 50`
```

Make sure that when you instantiate your `timepicker`, you use `showMeridian = false` as an option:

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker({
    showMeridian: false
});
```

**EDIT**: If you want other DatePickers to be normal:

- Copy `TimePicker` to a new object `TimePickerEx`,
- Override the functionality you want to (can be done nicely using `Object.create()`,
- Yeilding:

  ```
  function TimePickerEx() {
    return Object.create(TimePicker(), {
      setTime: function(time, ignoreWidget) {
        if (!time) {
          this.clear();
          return;
        }

        var timeArray,
            hour,
            minute,
            second,
            meridian;

        if (typeof time === 'object' && time.getMonth){
          // this is a date object
          hour    = time.getHours();
          minute  = time.getMinutes();
          second  = time.getSeconds();

          if (this.showMeridian){
            meridian = 'AM';
            if (hour > 12){
              meridian = 'PM';
              hour = hour % 12;
            }

            if (hour === 12){
              meridian = 'PM';
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (time.match(/p/i) !== null) {
            meridian = 'PM';
          } else {
            meridian = 'AM';
          }

          time = time.replace(/[^0-9\:]/g, '');

          timeArray = time.split(':');

          hour = timeArray[0] ? timeArray[0].toString() :                 timeArray.toString();
          minute = timeArray[1] ? timeArray[1].toString() : '';
          second = timeArray[2] ? timeArray[2].toString() : '';

          // idiot proofing
          if (hour.length > 4) {
            second = hour.substr(4, 2);
          }
          if (hour.length > 2) {
            minute = hour.substr(2, 2);
            hour = hour.substr(0, 2);
          }
          if (minute.length > 2) {
            second = minute.substr(2, 2);
            minute = minute.substr(0, 2);
          }
          if (second.length > 2) {
            second = second.substr(2, 2);
          }

          hour = parseInt(hour, 10);
          minute = parseInt(minute, 10);
          second = parseInt(second, 10);

          if (isNaN(hour)) {
            hour = 0;
          }
          if (isNaN(minute)) {
            minute = 0;
          }
          if (isNaN(second)) {
            second = 0;
          }

          if (this.showMeridian) {
            if (hour < 1) {
              hour = 1;
            } else if (hour > 12) {
              hour = 12;
            }
          } else {
            if (hour >= 51) {
              hour = 50;
            } else if (hour < 0) {
              hour = 0;
            }
            if (hour < 13 && meridian === 'PM') {
              hour = hour + 12;
            }
          }

          if (minute < 0) {
            minute = 0;
          } else if (minute >= 60) {
            minute = 59;
          }

          if (this.showSeconds) {
            if (isNaN(second)) {
              second = 0;
            } else if (second < 0) {
              second = 0;
            } else if (second >= 60) {
              second = 59;
            }
          }
        }

        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
        this.meridian = meridian;

        this.update(ignoreWidget);
      },
    }); 
  }
  ```

to use:

```
var timePickerEx = TimePickerEx();
```

and use a normal `TimePicker` for the rest.

Comment: What if you only want this functionality for one DateTime picker on the view? The rest should have the default hour shown?